# iPhone 5 struggling with autoresizingMask

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Just migrating my app to iphone 5 screen size and I'm struggling with autoresizing mask.

I don't understand when the mask is respected and when not. I've made 2 Testlabels, with the same autosizing mask option:

```
self.label1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
self.label2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
```

The frame of both label is defined programmatically. `label1` is set in the `viewDidLoad` ect., `label2` in a function which is called later. The y-coordinate of both frames is set to 10.

```
self.label1.frame = CGRectMake(110, 10, 50, 30);
self.label2.frame = CGRectMake(60, 10, 50, 30);
```

The effect is, that in the iphone 5 simulator, `label1` is displayed further down than `label2`. 
For `label1` (Frame set in `viewDidLoad`, the `autoresizingMask` is respected), for `label2` the mask is not respected.

So, why is autosizing not respected, when I set the frame outside `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Auto Layout. Are you by chance using a navigation controller?

Comment: oh yes, you're right, I changed the title from Auto Layout to autoresizingMask. And I'm not using a navigation controller.

Comment: It's further down because you set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin. Remove it and it'll be where you expect it to be.

Comment: And it's further down, because view is still loading. Put it in viewWillAppear to see what you want.

Comment: Hm, so autoresizingMask is respected in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear and not outside of these fct.!?

Comment: When you add the label, set the frame, then set the resizing mask to "flexible top", this means that as the view size changes, the top of the label will keep its original distance from the bottom of the label's superview. You need to know that in viewDidLoad, the view controller's view may not yet be the correct size. So when the view controller's view adjusts to it proper size, the labels will move down because you set them up to keep a constant distance from the bottom.

Comment: So far, I unterstand all of your comments. But I see a different problem. I describe another use case: I want to move a uiview near the bottom of the screen through animation. I can't simply set the new frame y coordinate to, maybe 460 and then the view is in iphone4 and iphone5 near the bottom. I have probably to work in this situations with "[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]-20". Is that the solution? To me it's inconsistent and I ve to rework a lot of animations for adapting to iphone5 screen size.